# Error resizing browser window in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, window-resize

I am developing a chrome extension and I wanted to resize the browser window to a specific size. I am using the `chrome.windows.update` method. This is the following code

```
chrome.windows.getLastFocused(function (window) {
  var updateInfo = {
    width: 700,
    height: 600,
    top: 50,
    left: 100,
  };
  (updateInfo.state = "normal"),
    chrome.windows.update(window.id, updateInfo);
});
```

It does resize the window, but it resizes to 614x375 (on brave) and 544x433 (for chrome).

I am using manifest version 3.

Not sure where am i going wrong. Can you please help me out.

TIA.

Comment: Assuming you don't have another extension (or an external utility) that adjusts the size, it's a bug in the browser.